# How to sort y-axis string values in flot chart

Tags: json, charts, flot

I would like to sort y-axis string values by asc/desc in flot chart. I am using jquery.flot.categories.js for displaying it.

Any help will be really appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first advice is to not use the categories plugin.  It's behavior is easily reproduced using the basic flot option of `ticks` (docs [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes)).  Setting up this option is all the categories plugin does anyway.

Then, if you want to resort the axis just toggle how you create the ticks:

```
var ascTicks = [[0,'A'],[1,'B'],[2,'C']];
var desTicks = [[0,'C'],[1,'B'],[2,'A']];
```

You can then write a utility function as well to convert categories into sorted ticks:

```
var categories = ['A','B','C'];
function createTicks(isReverse){
    categories.sort();
    if (isReverse){
       categories.reverse();
    }
    var ticks = [];
    $.each(categories, function(i,j){
       ticks.push([i,j]);
    });
    return ticks;
}
```

Use this in the options as:

```
yaxis:{
    ticks: createTicks(false)
}
```

[Here's an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/y2i4vCZc5tHpMRzCRih2?p=preview) where you can toggle the sorting of the ticks.